# How to find the foreach index?

Tags: php, loops, foreach

Is it possible to find the `foreach` index?

in a `for` loop as follows:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < 10; ++$i) {
   echo $i . ' ';
}
```

`$i` will give you the index.

Do I have to use the `for` loop or is there some way to get the index in the `foreach` loop?

Answer (score 1199, accepted):

```
foreach($array as $key=>$value) {
    // do stuff
}
```

`$key` is the index of each `$array` element

Comment: Depends on what the OP means by index:

  <?

  $a = array(3,5,'xx',4312,'sasas');

  unset($a[3]);

  foreach ($a as $k=>$v) print "\$k= $k and \$v = $v";

  ?>

Comment: definitely, this question isn't very specific, i took it to mean the OP was largely unaware of the $key=>$value syntax

Comment: well this is actually right, but should not be the accepted answer, since key can be a string too. say you do `$myarr['foo'] = 'bar';` this method fails

Comment: @Toskan Why would it fail? In an associative array the **only** index which exists is the string $key. So `foreach($array as $key=>$value)` would place `"foo"` in the `$key` exactly as you'd expect. Any numerical index could never be mapped to a specific element in the array. At best you could say its the n-th element, but if you were to use `for($i = 0; $i < count($array); $i++)` you could run in to the exact same issue with a numeric array if an index had been `unset()` or if the numeric index was manually decided (like `$array = [2 => "myvariable", "myOtherVariable"]`).

Comment: @Bison you are right in the meaning that it does not fail. But it fails to comply the OP question. He is looking for numerical values like the n-th element.

Comment: Like @Toskan says, this should not be the accepted answer.
I think it's better to just create a variable outside the loop and count from there, increasing it with `vatiable++;` on each iteration. The traditional way, but has always worked.

Comment: Today, visiting this, I found out that iterating over an XML element the $key value always show "entry" because the XML object didn't assigned a numeric value and all the pieces were called "entry". Consider: `$xmlstr = "<feed><entry><title>Title 1</title></entry><entry><title>Title 2</title></entry><entry><title>Title 3</title></entry></feed>";` so doing: `$content = SimpleXMLElement($xmlstr);` and then `foreach($content->entry as $key=>$el) {` $key will always show "entry" instead of any unique index that can work to identify the single entry. Using a counter variable was the only choice

Comment: This answer is only valid for Indexed arrays, $key won't return index for an Associative array. Its better to create a variable outside the loop and increment it on every loop or stick to the good old for loop.

Answer (score 216):

You can put a hack in your `foreach`, such as a field incremented on each run-through, which is exactly what the `for` loop gives you in a numerically-indexed array. Such a field would be a pseudo-index that needs manual management (increments, etc).

A `foreach` will give you your index in the form of your `$key` value, so such a hack shouldn't be necessary.

e.g., in a **`foreach`**

```
$index = 0;
foreach($data as $key=>$val) {
    // Use $key as an index, or...

    // ... manage the index this way..
    echo "Index is $index\n";
    $index++;
}
```

Comment: Having a value incremented in a loop is hardly a 'hack.'

Comment: @ThomasMcCabe One might even say it's one of the core uses for a loop.

Answer (score 33):

It should be noted that you can call [`key()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.key.php) on any array to find the current key its on. As you can guess `current()` will return the current value and `next()` will move the array's pointer to the next element.

Comment: This should be useful if you want to use a plain old PHP associative array to store data which is to be exposed via the Iterable interface (where you need to keep track of where you are in a loop).

Comment: +1 for the alternative, but a function call in every iteration is a little heavier than using preassigned variables (i.e. using the `$key` from `$key=>$value`)... However, I bet the lower performance is non-significant/perceptible in a simple loop.

Answer (score 26):

Owen has a good answer.  If you want just the key, and you are working with an array this might also be useful.

```
foreach(array_keys($array) as $key) {
//  do stuff
}
```

Comment: And if you need the index, `foreach(array_keys($array) as $index=>$key)`.

Answer (score 19):

You can create `$i` outside the loop and do `$i++` at the bottom of the loop.

Comment: It's important to note that this approach gives the current iteration of the loop, NOT the current index of the iterated array.

Answer (score 13):

Follow this code:

```
foreach ($lists as $key=>$value) {
    echo $key+1;
}
```

it is easy and clean code

Answer (score 10):

These two loops are equivalent (bar the safety railings of course):

```
for ($i=0; $i<count($things); $i++) { ... }

foreach ($things as $i=>$thing) { ... }
```

eg

```
for ($i=0; $i<count($things); $i++) {
    echo "Thing ".$i." is ".$things[$i];
}

foreach ($things as $i=>$thing) {
    echo "Thing ".$i." is ".$thing;
}
```

Comment: Not if it is an associative array

Answer (score 9):

I use `++$key` instead of `$key++` to start from 1. Normally it starts from 0.

```php
@foreach ($quiz->questions as $key => $question)
 <h2> Question: {{++$key}}</h2>
 <p>{{$question->question}}</p>
@endforeach
```

Output:

```
Question: 1
......
Question:2
.....
.
.
.
```

Answer (score 7):

PHP arrays have internal pointers, so try this:

```
foreach($array as $key => $value){
   $index = current($array);
}
```

Works okay for me (only very preliminarily tested though).

Comment: $key is the $index and current($array) is equal to $value. So both is not required, just use $index and $value.

Comment: I think you mean to use $key and $value. @doraemon

Comment: Yes, this answer is wrong. The current($array) will give you the first element of the $array used in this example. https://onlinephp.io/c/95a7c

Comment: You can simply use the $key variable as your index, here is the example: https://onlinephp.io/c/3d5ac.  But if you need index unrelated to keys of array, you will need this syntax: foreach (array_keys($array) as $index=>$key) . This can happen if you have an array like ['a'=>2, 'x'=>4, 'c'=>5]. But in this case, you can not use for loop like for ($i=0;$i <3;$i++) {}. So $key => $value approach answers the question well.

Answer (score 5):

Jonathan is correct.  PHP arrays act as a map table mapping keys to values.  in some cases you can get an index if your array is defined, such as

```
$var = array(2,5);

for ($i = 0; $i < count($var); $i++) {
    echo $var[$i]."\n";
}
```

your output will be

```
2
5
```

in which case each element in the array has a knowable index, but if you then do something like the following

```
$var = array_push($var,10);

for ($i = 0; $i < count($var); $i++) {
    echo $var[$i]."\n";
}
```

you get no output.  This happens because arrays in PHP are not linear structures like they are in most languages.  They are more like hash tables that may or may not have keys for all stored values.  Hence foreach doesn't use indexes to crawl over them because they only have an index if the array is defined.  If you need to have an index, make sure your arrays are fully defined before crawling over them, and use a for loop.

Comment: Yes, this is why in PHP we must "join arrays" by *keys* and not by *indexes*... See also [array_map](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php)(func,$a,$b).

Comment: Ops, dear reader and @TheBrawnyMan, remember also that your example is like a [array_push()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php) bug (!). The  recomendation is to use `$var[] = 10;` (see PHP link to guide), so the second `for` loop outputs the expected results.

Answer (score 3):

I normally do this when working with associative arrays:

```
foreach ($assoc_array as $key => $value) {
 //do something
}
```

This will work fine with non-associative arrays too.  $key will be the index value.  If you prefer, you can do this too:

```
foreach ($array as $indx => $value) {
  //do something
}
```

Comment: What's the 'alternative' for? You know this is the same, besides the variable names? So the last sentence and code block is unnecessary, I'd say - if it does anything it just confuses..

Comment: @Dennis98 The difference is that one of them has an associative array as an input and the other one has a numeric array. Although I guess it'd be better if the answer was a bit more verbose.

Answer (score 3):

I solved this way, when I had to use the foreach index and value in the same context:

```
$array = array('a', 'b', 'c');
foreach ($array as $letter=>$index) {

  echo $letter; //Here $letter content is the actual index
  echo $array[$letter]; // echoes the array value

}//foreach
```

Answer (score -1):

```
foreach(array_keys($array) as $key) {
//  do stuff
}
```

Answer (score -2):

I would like to add this, I used this in laravel to just index my table:

- With $loop->index
- I also preincrement it with ++$loop to start at 1

My Code:

```
@foreach($resultsPerCountry->first()->studies as $result)
  <tr>
    <td>{{ ++$loop->index}}</td>                                    
  </tr>
@endforeach
```

Comment: This question was not asked for laravel. The `$loop` variable cannot be used because it is asked for general PHP.