# php built in counter for what iteration foreach loop is currently in

Tags: php, foreach, indexing, iterator

I have an associative array. Two dimensions which I am iterating through like this

```
foreach ( $order_information as $sector_index => $sector_value ){
echo 'sector : ' . current($order_information) ;
echo '<br>';
    foreach ( $sector_value as $line_index => $line_value ){

    }
}
```

The `current()` is an attempt to get the iteration the loop is in. [It seems like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/141108/how-to-find-the-foreach-index) should give me that. However, elsewhere on that page there is the suggestions that you just do like

```
$index = 0
foreach ( $array as $key => $val ) {
    echo $index;
    $index++;
}
```

I wonder if I am using current incorrectly, as `echo 'sector : ' . current($order_information);` just prints `sector : Array`

Is $index++ bad syntax? Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: `current()` gives you the element pointed by the array's internal pointer. It will **not** give you an index. The proper way to do this is to use a counter, like you're doing in your second example. No, there's nothing wrong with `$index++`. It would also help if you could post how this `$order_information` array actually looks like.

Comment: No `$index++` is not bad syntax it is a shorter way of saying `$index = $index + 1`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Answer

As far as I know there is no build in numeric counter in a `foreach` loop in PHP.

So you need your own counter variable. Your example code looks quite good to do that.

```
$index = 0;
foreach($array as $key => $val) {
    $index++;
}
```

By the way, `$index++;` is fine.

### Example

Here is an example illustrating which variable stores which value.

```
$array = array(
    "first"  => 100,
    "secnd" => 200,
    "third"  => 300,
);

$index = 0;
foreach($array as $key => $val) {
    echo "index: " . $index . ", ";
    echo "key: "   . $key   . ", ";
    echo "value: " . $val   . "\n";
    $index++;
}
```

The output will be that.

```
index: 0, key: first, value: 100
index: 1, key: secnd, value: 200
index: 2, key: third, value: 300
```

### Current-Function

I think you misunderstood `current($array)`. It gives you the value pointed by an internal array pointer, which can be moved using `next($array)`, `prev($array)` and `end($array)`.

Take a look at the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.current.php) to make thinks clear.