# PHP getting sql result by using for loop (or index number) and not foreach in controller codeigniter

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter, foreach

I have a query that goes like this:

```
function getnames(){
        $sql = "select * from names where status = '1'";

        $query = $this->db->query($sql);

        if($query->num_rows()>0){
            return $query->result();
        }
        else{
            return null;
        }
    }
```

This function is already loaded in the **new_model.php**. I am using CodeIgniter.

Then in the controller, I use a function that returns the query result. I already have this in the controller:

```
    function getnames(){
    return $this->new_model->getnames();
}
```

What I want to do is that instead of using foreach() loop in getting the array result, I want to use something else that will let me use an index number. How can I do this? Please help. Thanks!

Comment: Why are you against foreach? Is there any specific, concrete reason?

Comment: @DamienPirsy I need an index number. I need the index number for other parts of the code.

Comment: @achll Do you mean out of the result set object you want only a particular row?

Comment: @ICanHasKittenz I think no. I just want the index of current array result.

Comment: @achll Refer each column by index number rather than name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$index is the number you are looking for.

$name is the value of the $names[$index]

Answer (score 0):

How about using `foreach ($names as $index => $name)` ?

Comment: I also read that from here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/141108/how-to-find-the-foreach-index but I don't get it how to use $index and $name?

Comment: Please explain your answer in brief.