# How to use foreach in PHP?

Tags: php

I am trying to write my below code using `foreach` statement in PHP. I just started with PHP so still learning.

```
$myarray = array ("Hello World", "Hello Tree", "Hello, Proc!");
for($i = 0; $i < count($myarray); $i++) {
    $myarray[$i] .= " ($i)";
}
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Did you look at the manual for the function? http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php Maybe there is something specific from there you are having issues with?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to find the foreach index](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/141108/how-to-find-the-foreach-index)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
 $myarray = array ("Hello World", "Hello Tree", "Hello, Proc!");
 foreach($myarray as $key => &$item) {
     $item .= " ($key)";
 }
```

`&$item` makes the $item a pointer instead of a copy of the array item. So any changes you make to $item will be reflected in the original. `$key` is equivalent to your array index counter `$i`. See the [foreach](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) reference for more information.

Answer (score 2):

```
$myarray = array ("Hello World", "Hello Tree", "Hello, Proc!");
$i = 0;
foreach($myarray as $arrayElement) {
    $i++; //Foreach item in the array it adds 1 to the variable i.
    $myarray[$i] = " $i"; //it sets the element[i] to the value of i
    echo $myarray[$i]; //it displays your array on the screen
}
```

This the the long way (but easy in my opinion) to do it, I don't recommend this way(use $key) but you can use it to store everything in a variable to know what your doing until you really understand the loop.

Answer (score 1):

If you replace your FOR-loop with a FOREACH-loop, it would look like this :

```
$myarray = array ("Hello World", "Hello Tree", "Hello, Proc!");
foreach ($myarray as $key => $value) {
    $myarray[$key] .= " ($key)";
}
```

For more info on foreach, take a look at [**the official documentation**](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php).

Answer (score 1):

Here is what you want .

```
$myarray = array ("Hello World", "Hello Tree", "Hello, Proc!");
 foreach($myarray as $key => $value) {
     $myarray[$key].= " ($key)";
 }
```

**Explaination :**

`$key` is equivalent your array index counter `$i` and `$value` is the value of array `$myarray`. For more information you can see [this](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php)

Comment: Might want to change your value to item or vice versa. Also you either need to initialize value as pointer or use index when appending value.

Comment: i think i made typo mistake . @Achshar sir i have updated my answer :) .

Comment: Lol I'm no sir, sir.