# How to control foreach loop iteration in php

Tags: php, loops, iteration

I want to fetch some data from database in the form of list. Following is my loop:

```
<div class="col-sm-4">
<ul>
<?php
foreach($subjects as $s)
{
echo "<li>$s->subject_title</li>";
}
?>
</u>
</div>
```

Now this loop prints data in one column and the user have to scroll down to view the last elements. I want to control the loop in such a way that after printing first 10 elements, it must start again from the div tag and print the next 10 elements and so on. I want to show the data in such a way that the user don't have to scroll down.

For example, I want to print the data in the following way:

[image]

I write the following code but it is not working. The div tag is only applied to the first 10 elements, and not on the rest of the data.

```
  <div class="col-sm-6">
            <ul class="filter-list">
                         <?php
                         $i = 0;
                         foreach($main_subjs as $i=>$ms)
                         {
                         if($i == 10) {
                         echo "</ul></div><div class='col-sm-6'><ul>";
                         $i++;
                         continue;
                         }
                         echo "<li><a href='#'>$ms->mains_title</a></li>";
                         }
                         ?>
            </ul>
                    </div>
```

Please Help.

Comment: I need an answer, not a question.

Comment: you need to learn some manners. short answer [Modulus](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.arithmetic.php)

Comment: This is not a code writing service. We are not here to do your job for you, or tell you how to do your job. YOU write code, we (maybe) try help fix it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to find the foreach index](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/141108/how-to-find-the-foreach-index)

Comment: @Ajmal Razeel, "Please Help." doesn't make sense when you say "I need an answer, not a question"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an arugment for a loop you can also use the key of array

```
foreach($subjects as $i=>$s)
```

When you will be able to "control" your loop, e.g.:

```
<div>
<?php
foreach($subjects as $i=>$s) {
  if($i> 0 && $i % 5 == 0) {
    echo "</div><div>";
  }
  echo "<li>$s->subject_title</li>";
}
?>
</div>
```