# Why I can't do write row number by rating on last change

Tags: php, pdo

I want to write row number by point rating. But I can't do it this for last point.

```
    <?php
               $self=$db->query("SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY exam_name DESC");
               $a1=1;
               foreach ($self as $order)
               {

                   if($order['exam_name']==$gb['exam_name']) //$gb = selected exam by user id

                   {
                       echo $a1;
                       break;

                   }
                   $a1++;

               }
    ?>
```

Comment: If you need to "break" out of a results loop, you're not constructing the right query.

Comment: I deleted "break", no change. All point's ok but last saved points rating dont writing.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to find the foreach index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/141108/how-to-find-the-foreach-index)

Comment: No, fetch it was used twice. I deleted one and working.

Comment: I would just let the MySQL do the work, but you would need to start `$a1 = 0` before the loop and `$a1++` directly inside the loop above your if statement. You never reach the last increment.

Comment: $a1 variable it does not matter, because used foreach.